# Google Places API search for a PLace in GLOBE

Tags: php, python, google-maps, dictionary, bing-maps

I want the user to enter a `name of a place`, and it will return all the matching places, User will select one from the list, In [`Google Place API`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/index.html#PlaceSearches) I need to provide a lat, lng and search within a certain radius.

But I want no radius, rather I want it to search the globe, much like the place search in Google Earth.

Right now I am planning to observe Google Earth under `wireshark` and I'll repeat the same. Is that lawsuit ? or is there any other straight way to do the same ?

I've no problem in using services like bing or any others, if they offer the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about entering a lat,lng of 0,0 and a radius of 12,500 miles? That should cover the world.

Comment: The radius is limited to 50,000 meters which restricts the global search, 50,000 meters would span a region or district I think